# Change newsletter subscription message position

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, newsletter

When we are **subscribing to** or **unsubscribing from** any newsletter from the [Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page, it redirects to the parent site and the confirmation message is appearing in the top right corner.

**When subscribing to the newsletter:**

> [image: When subscribing to the newsletter]

**When unsubscribing from the newsletter:**

> [image: When unsubscribing from the newsletter]

Can the confirmation message appear in the bottom right of the screen, so it doesn't hide the top bar content?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it only displays for roughly 4 seconds after the subscribe / unsubscribe operation and then it fades away. I honestly don't think moving it is going to be useful because it obscures the top bar for such a short period of time.

I'm marking this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but comment if you feel really strongly about it.